# Is it possible to show my values from my object into an AmChart?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, amcharts

I am working on a project that one of the ideas is to get the values from database and show in a graphic funnel...

But all the project is in spring mvc with thymeleaf, and the graphic in javascript

Is it possible to show the values?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Proposition</th>
            <th>Ticket</th>
            <th>Week's Number </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="client : ${clients}">
            <td class="text-center" th:text="${client.ID}"></td>
            <td class="text-right"
                th:text="${client.Name}"></td>
            <td class="text-right"
                th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(client.Proposition, 0, 'POINT', 2, 'COMMA')}"></td>
            <td class="text-right"
                th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(client.Ticket, 0, 'POINT', 2, 'COMMA')}"></td>
            <td class="text-right"
            th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(client.weeksNumber, 0, 'POINT', 2, 'COMMA')}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="chartdiv"> </div>
```

The chart is in the .js of the project.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's possible (there are many examples of how to use thymeleaf variables in javascript).

Comment: Really? could you show me them? I am searching but without results, my head is exploding :p

Comment: [Here](https://www.concretepage.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-javascript-inline-example-with-variable) are [some](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining) [examples](https://github.com/cahlen/springone-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/index.html).